# Is it compulsory to write registerWithClass or registerWithNib for tableviewcell in iOS 10?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, ios10

I would like to know that is it compulsory to `[self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"myidentifier"];` in viewDidLoad and when `UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"myidentifier"];` in cellForRowAtIndexPath? for iOS 10.0?

Because in iOS 10.0 beta it kills app when I did not registerClass. But it works in early version of iOS without registering it.

Thanks all.

Comment: CALL THIS ONE `[self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"myidentifier"];` IN INSIDE CELL FOR ROWATINDEX

Comment: Are you using a Xib or storyboard?

Comment: No Just Class. And @Anbu.Karthik it works fine when i register in viewdidload. My question is that is it compulsory? If yes then why?

Comment: see this bro https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-register-a-cell-for-uitableviewcell-reuse

Comment: I have not created any Nib. I took a Cell in tableview, did not created a customise class for that so I can registerClass:.

Comment: Ok thanks for sharing Anbu.Karthik

Comment: @ManishPatel - welcome bro,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no, is not mandatory.

If you are using Storyboard, no need to registerClass, as storyboard settings already associates cell to its Class, even if custom class.
(you have to set the class type in "custom class" pane in property for cell).

tested on Xcode 7.3 objC:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CustomTableViewCell *cell = (CustomTableViewCell*) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CELLID" forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

in  swift 3/Xcode 8:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CELLID", for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
..
```